# How to retrieve data from database and display in Ttreeview in delphi

Tags: delphi, treeview, delphi-7

Please help me to populate a tree view from SQL database dynamically. I am very new to delphi

[image]

and step by step processes are welcome. I have two table formats given in the picture below and i want to fill the tree view from database accordingly. I searched on other resource sites also but didn't find the solution what i am looking for.

I am stuck. Please help me guys....
Many many thanks in advance.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  // node : TTreeList;
  i: Integer;
  MyTreeNode1,MyTreeNode2 : TTreeNode;
begin
   with TreeList1.Items do
   begin
        Clear;
        MyTreeNode1 := Add(nil, 'Table');
        ADOTable1.First;
        while ADOTable1 do
        begin
            AddChild(MyTreeNode1,'B') ;
            AddChild(MyTreeNode1,'c');
            Next;
        end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Have you seen these? http://users.iafrica.com/d/da/dart/zen/Articles/TTreeView/TTreeView_Main.html and http://delphi.about.com/b/2003/07/16/treeview-to-the-max.htm

Comment: And your process has two-steps. Step 1 is retrieving the data from the database. Do you have your SQL query for that? What have you tried so far and what is failing? Show some code.

Comment: @JanDoggen I have stored that data into a dataset "TTable" but when I want to retrieve and show on delphi form it is failing.. I cant retrieve data from TTable .. My code isnt working there

Comment: There is no way you can have all the required data in a TTable. You have linked tables, you should either (1) retrieve your data with an SQL statement to link them, and then use a Delphi data component that returns that SQL data, then walk through that data and build up your tree, or (2) (if you insist on using 'single table' components like TTable) use several TTables, walk through the first one, walk through associated data in the second one, buld up your tree. It looks as if the first problem you need to solve is "How do I walk through my data in a way that allows me to build the tree".

Comment: You have now posted two related questions and you are pasting **incorrect code** from one **as a comment** into the other. Fix the code, insert it into this question, kill the other question.

Comment: @JanDoggen are u able to see the code that I have pasted.. Thank u

Comment: Your `While` statement is incorrect. It should read `While Not ADOTable1.EOF Do` and the `Next` statement should read `ADOTable1.Next;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to `TADOQuery` and then try something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CurrentDeptID, RecordDeptID: Integer;
  RootNode, DeptNode: TTreeNode;
begin
  CurrentDeptID := 0;
  TreeList1.Items.Clear;
  RootNode := TreeList1.Items.Add(nil, 'Departments');
  DeptNode := nil;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT sd.DeptID, sd.Name, d.Dept FROM SubDepartments sd INNER JOIN Departments d ON (sd.DeptID = d.DeptID) ORDER BY d.Dept, sd.Name';
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  try
    ADOQuery1.First;
    while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      RecordDeptID := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('DeptID').AsInteger;
      if (DeptNode = nil) or (RecordDeptID <> CurrentDeptID) then
      begin
        DeptNode := TreeList1.Items.AddChild(RootNode, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Dept').AsString);
        CurrentDeptID := RecordDeptID;
      end;
      TreeList1.Items.AddChild(DeptNode, ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Name').AsString);
      ADOQuery1.Next;
    end;
  finally
    ADOQuery1.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: "+1" How to add sub nodes for an existing node after checking some condition like if 'name1'='name2' then add subnode.. thank you its working very fine..

Comment: It really depends on what the subnodes represent and where their data comes from in relation to the other tables. An SQL dataset is pretty flat, it is not meant for building a tree of data, so you might need multiple queries, or multiple JOINs.